# How to set up scopeBar and cancelButton for UIsearchBar inside UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I have a viewController with a navigation bar and I am trying to put a UISearchBar inside the navBar. It apparently is not as simple as I thought it was.

Here is the code I currently have:

```
private func setupNavigationBarItems(){
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    searchBar.placeholder = "Search Users + Songs"

    navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 20/255, green: 20/255, blue: 20/255, alpha: 1)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}

func setupSearchBar() {
    self.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.blackTranslucent
    self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    self.searchBar.placeholder = "Search songs + users"
    self.searchBar.backgroundColor = .clear        
    self.searchBar.backgroundImage = nil
    self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = false
    self.searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .clear)
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
    UISegmentedControl.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 20/255, green: 40/255, blue: 60/255, alpha: 1)
}

lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 20))

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

        self.searchBar.showsScopeBar = true
        self.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = ["Songs", "Users"]
        self.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex = 0
        self.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.searchBar.frame.size.width = 335
    }
}
```

This gets the searchBar to appear in the navBar, but that is all. The cancel button does not show and the scopeBar does not show either when `didBeginEditing` is executed. How can I get the scopeBar and cancel button to show inside the navBar?